# Dynamics 365 and Azure integration

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, integration, microsoft-dynamics

I am building an app for Dynamics 365.

The app should trigger on lead creation, make an HTTP call to an external service, get some data, update the lead with the new data.

I would also need to update single and a batch of leads ad-hoc when needed from my service by making an HTTP call to the data API from my side to the customer's instance.

This app should be installable and ran on a customer's instance of Dynamics.

From what I gather, one way to do this is to use Azure "Wep API" app and Dynamics 365 OData Web API.

After 3 days of going to the docs and MSDN I do not have any answers to the following questions so I need the help you the good folks over here.

My questions are:

1. How would I implement a trigger to do something on lead creation or update? ( similar to a SF before insert trigger )
2. Are there any limitations on the number of HTTP requests made outside per second / minute / day?
3. Are there any limitation of the number of HTTP requests I can make to update leads in bulk?
4. Are there any limitation on the running time?

I was not able to locate any documentation on this and to be honest I am blown away by the sheer complexity and confusion around the entire MS cloud ecosystem, madness... so please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was not able to locate any documentation on this and to be honest I
>   am blown away by the sheer complexity and confusion around the entire
>   MS cloud ecosystem

This question is perhaps a little too broad. A couple of pointers:

- Microsoft make a lot of software, knowing which bits you need is half the challenge. For documentation try starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/).
- These bits of software whilst often sold or presented as a 'package', are usually quite separate applications.
- It seems you are looking at; [Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/) (previously known as CRM) and [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/) (which itself is composed of dozens of sub services).
- I suggest you start by learning about each application, and then move onto integrating them together. For 365 I have a [blogged](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/getting-started-with-coded-development-in-microsoft-dynamics-365/) a series of articles you may find useful.

Regarding your specific points for Microsoft Dynamics 365:

1. Workflow with a [custom workflow activity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx), or a [plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx) is a good option.
2. I don't believe so.
3. Depends. In general no. If you are using [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj863631.aspx), then yes there is a limit of 1000.
4. Yes, if you are running in the [sandbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx).

> Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online & on-premises) support the execution of
>   plug-ins and custom workflow activities in an isolated environment. In
>   this isolated environment, also known as a sandbox...If the sandbox
>   worker process that hosts this custom code exceeds threshold CPU,
>   memory, or handle limits or is otherwise unresponsive, that process
>   will be killed by the platform.

Comment: So from what I gather it seems like the only way for me to write an equivalent to a SF trigger would be to get the Dynamics SDK and put some C# of .NET together? Seems like I am forced to develop on Windows for this? are there any other ways to achieve a trigger functionality?

Comment: @AssafMoldavsky Not used SF so can't comment. But if you want the communication to start from CRM, you need to put something into CRM, and CRM is built on the .NET platform, so yeah...

Comment: @AssafMoldavsky, you might find this interesting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334766.aspx

Comment: thank you for your help! you have put me on a good path. I have spent almost the whole day yesterday to understand that I would be able to do this with VSCode and will need the VS Community with the whole .NET shabang to do this trigger. Setting this up now... such a difficult road so far