# How to setup Azure web service for Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Good morning everyone,

My apologies if this post is too similar to this post:

[Dynamics 365 and Azure integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158280/dynamics-365-and-azure-integration)

but I am struggling to understand exactly what is needed in order to setup a web service on an Azure server that is consumable by a Dynamics 365 plugin. Based on my research it appears that it goes as follows but I would like to see if any knows of a better guide.

1.) Construct the web service as normal on the Azure Windows Server.

2.) Register a proper DNS Domain name (friendly-name) and route it to the Azure server.

3.) Secure that Azure server/URL with a certificate.

4.) Call the web service from my C# Dynamics 365 plugin.

Is that everything or might I be missing something critical? Thank you!

Comment: Rather than building a complete web service, you might want to look into using the out-of-box Azure integration and creating some flavor of queue listener instead (which can be less overhead than building a public-facing API). For more info: [Azure integration with Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334766.aspx).  Furthermore, if you do want to go with a straight API, one option for a free SSL cert is [Let's Encrypt](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20073)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 might be an issue, given you want to use certificate based security, not sure that will work, you might need to use another mechanism, e.g. basic user name and password. Otherwise looks okay.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)

> **Web access**
>
> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
>   support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
>   feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
>   apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
> - Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
> - IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
> - **Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended.** There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving
>     those credentials.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will start with 1 through 3 first, then update this post. I will keep you posted. My hope is that this can function as a walkthrough eventually.